# Could not find the option translate in navigation menu of SharePoint online - Multilingual

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, multilingual

I want enable multilingual in SharePoint online.

I have enable multiple languages in Setting -> Language Setting

[image]

Then I could able to create page for Chinese (Simplified) language.

But when I try to translate navigation menu. I could not able to find the translate option.

[image]

I have followed this article to create the multilingual site: [Create multilingual communication sites, pages, and news](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-communication-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c)

Please guide me to sort-out the issue.

Comment: How much time you have waited after enabling language settings? I have followed the same steps previously & I am able to create translations for navigation links without any problem.

Comment: I have setup yesterday. Still I could not see the translate option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I am posting here, it may useful for others.
I have login for the translator user account (eg: Owner Test).
Then go to ViewAccount -> Settings & Privacy

[image]

[image]

Then go to the Display language and change it to the relevant language (Chinese).
All the SharePoint controls will change it to Chinese.

Then go to the Navigation menu and modify the menu items, it will modify the menu items of the Chinese page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange phenomenon,please switch to other communication sites to compare the results.

[image]

If the issue still exists, we suggest you raise a new service request to Microsoft:

[image]