# Navigation is not translated on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, managed-navigation, language

I would like to translate the navigation of the SharePoint sites, I have EN,DE,PL sites and nav menu About Us, Home, Services.

I have enabled languages in SharePoint Language setting, I have selected Managed Metadata from /_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx and added preferred languages as English, German, Polish in Delve.

After setting these changes when I switch between the languages I still see them in English.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Navigation links will not be translated to each language automatically, you have to do it **manually** for each navigation link.

[image]

> To show the site name, navigation, and footer of your site in the different languages you've made available, each must be translated **manually**. You can add or update translations when you edit any of these elements.

**Source Documentation**: [Set up a multilingual site name, navigation and footer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-sharepoint-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c#bkmk_muitranslations)

Comment: I have edited the main question, I have manually added the wording when I switch to German I still them in English. Page is being translated but not the navigation.

Comment: How much time you waited after changing the text manually? Also, check if this thread helps: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293594/could-not-find-the-option-translate-in-navigation-menu-of-sharepoint-online-mu

Comment: I think almost 2-3 hrs, Is there something it works only on browser language setting