# SharePoint Online Multi-Language Private Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, intranet

I have created a private group with two languages added. However, I am noticing that the navigation and the site name is not being translated to both languages.

I did a quick research and added the translation manually to both sites. However, still, the navigation and the site items stayed in one language. Meanwhile, the page content changed in both languages manually.

Kindly, advise on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you translated the navigation menu items too?

Comment: I have translated it. Surprisingly, it is not reflecting.

Comment: Not sure if this thread might help. Their answer is to change your O365 account Displayed Language. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293594/could-not-find-the-option-translate-in-navigation-menu-of-sharepoint-online-mu

Comment: I'll test this and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What method are you using to change your language? The little on-page dropdown that SharePoint's Multilingual Page Publishing feature provides does not change your interface language. To change that, you have to change your profile language (note, changing the account language often but not necessarily forces a change to your profile language).

Click your picture or name at the top, then "My Microsoft 365 profile", then "Update profile", expand "How can I change language and regional settings?" and click "here", click "...". select "Language and region", update "My Display Languages", scroll down and click "Save all and close".

It may take several minutes for the new language choice to propagate, and after that the navigation will sometimes be cached in the other language.  It changes eventually, but one trick is to navigate to a classic page and back to a modern one to flush the cache if you are impatient.

Comment: You are right the interface language only changes within the display language. Thank you for your answer.